# Rename files by md5 checksum

Tags: rename, checksum, md5, md5sum

What program can I use to rename files with their calculated md5 checksums?
GUI or CLI Programs for Linux or Windows or scripts for DOS or the Linux terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "rename files with their calculated checksums"? You want to rename them to the value of their checksums or you want to change their name *based* on the value of the sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in Python if it is what you are looking for.  It will take and calculate an md5 for a file and then rename the file that sum.  Will work on *nix/Windows/?

```
/usr/bin/env python

import os, hashlib

file = 'path/to/file'


def main():

  h = hashlib.md5(file)
  output = h.hexdigest()
  os.rename( file, output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be indented?

Comment: yes, my mistake the code formating screwed my up, I wrote this in the window, I will make the edit.

Comment: This would be more useful if it took the path as an argument and performed the operation recursively if the argument was a directory ;)

Comment: It would but would not be as simple of an answer.  I personally would use BASH for this and take the filename as an arg and search for it with locate -b, calculate a hash with md5sum and the change the name with mv.  The OP talked about x-platform so I used Python, Perl scares me.